# CLI Dart: onPause, onResume, onDone not firing up as expected

Tags: events, stream, dart, command-line-interface

I am experimenting Dart, and I can't explain two observations.

1. I wonder why the "`onDone`" handler assigned to a stream subscription does not fire up.
2. I wonder why the "`onPause`" and "`onResume`" handlers fire up only once.

The code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

/// This class encapsulates all the necessary data used by the "onValue" event
/// handler (the construct avoids using global variables).
class OnValueHandlerContainer {
  static StreamSubscription<int> _streamSubscriber;

  static setStreamSubscriber(StreamSubscription<int> stream) {
    _streamSubscriber = stream;
  }

  // This static method is the handler executed when a event is received through
  // the stream.
  //
  // WARNING: you have absolutely no idea when this handler will be executed.
  // Do not assume that it will be executed right after the execution of the code
  // that emits an event. It may be executed several lines (of codes) below the
  // line that emits the event. It may well be executed after the end of the
  // script.
  static void onValue(int value) {
    // At this point: the state of the subscription is (inevitably) "active".
    print("onValue: An event has been raised. The associated value is ${value}!");
    print("         Pause the subscription. Wait for 1 second. Resume the subscription");

    // Note 1: once a Dart function starts executing, it continues executing until
    //         it exits. When managing interrupts in C, it is necessary to protect
    //         interrupt handlers from being interrupted. This is not the case in
    //         Dart : a function (and, thus, an event handler) cannot be interrupted
    //         by the occurrence of another event.
    //         => The code below has no sense, other than experimentation.
    // Note 2: while paused, the subscription will not fire any events. If it receives
    //         events from its source, they will be buffered until the subscription
    //         is resumed.
    _streamSubscriber.pause();
    sleep(Duration(seconds: 1));
    _streamSubscriber.resume();

    // At this point: the state of the subscription is "active".
  }
}

main() async {

  // Create a controller.
  // A StreamController gives you a new stream and a way to add events to the stream
  // at any point, and from anywhere. The stream has all the logic necessary to handle
  // listeners and pausing. You return the stream and keep the controller to yourself.
  StreamController<int> sc = StreamController<int>(
      onListen: () => print("Controller: the stream has been assigned a listener!"),
      onCancel: () => print("Controller: the stream has been canceled!"),
      // As you may notice, the event handlers are not executed every time the
      // subscription gets paused or resumed.
      //
      // This behaviour comes from these facts:
      // - Dart is single-threaded.
      // - An event handler cannot be interrupted: once a Dart function starts
      //   executing, it continues executing until it exits. In other words, Dart
      //   functions can’t be interrupted by other Dart code.
      //   See https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop
      // - A stream is a FIFO.
      onPause:  () => print("Controller: the stream has been paused!"),
      onResume: () => print("Controller: the stream has been resumed!")
  );

  // Get the stream created by the stream controller.
  // Right now, this stream has no assigned listener.
  Stream<int> stream = sc.stream;
  print("Does the stream provided by the controller have a listener ? ${sc.hasListener ? 'yes' : 'no'} - the answer should be no.");

  // Push values into the stream controlled by the stream controller.
  // Because no listener subscribed to the stream, these values are just stored
  // into the stream.
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    print("Send the value ${i} into the stream.");
    sc.add(i);
  }

  // Add a listener to the stream.
  // Now the stream has an assigned listener.
  StreamSubscription<int> subscriber = stream.listen(OnValueHandlerContainer.onValue);
  OnValueHandlerContainer.setStreamSubscriber(subscriber);
  subscriber.onDone(() => print("The subscription is done!"));
  print("Does the stream provided by the controller have a listener ? ${sc.hasListener ? 'yes' : 'no'} - the answer should be yes.");

  // Wait for 10 seconds.
  print("Start waiting for 10 seconds");
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10)).then((var v) => print("10 seconds ellapsed!"));
  print("End of script");
}
```

The result:

```
Does the stream provided by the controller have a listener ? no - the answer should be no.
Send the value 0 into the stream.
Send the value 1 into the stream.
Send the value 2 into the stream.
Controller: the stream has been assigned a listener!
Does the stream provided by the controller have a listener ? yes - the answer should be yes.
Start waiting for 10 seconds
End of script
onValue: An event has been raised. The associated value is 0!
         Pause the subscription. Wait for 1 second. Resume the subscription
Controller: the stream has been paused!
onValue: An event has been raised. The associated value is 1!
         Pause the subscription. Wait for 1 second. Resume the subscription
onValue: An event has been raised. The associated value is 2!
         Pause the subscription. Wait for 1 second. Resume the subscription
Controller: the stream has been resumed!
10 seconds ellapsed!
```

Basically, the code provided performs the following actions :

- A stream controller is created.
- 3 events are injected into the stream provided by the controller.
- A listener subscribes to the stream provided by the controller.
- We assign an "`onDone`" handler to the listener subscription.
- Within the stream listener (`OnValueHandlerContainer::onValue`) we pause and resume the subscription.

The stream listener fires up 3 times, as expected.

However:

- the "`onDone`" handler is never executed. I expect it to be executed at the end of the script execution, while the controller is being destroyed (and, thus, the subscription gets closed).
- the "`onPause`" and "`onResume`" handlers fire up only once. I expect them to be executed 3 times.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

The reason you don't get a "done" event is that you never `close` the stream subscription.

The reason you don't get more "pause" events is that the stream subscription is *clever*.

The first thing you do is to add a lot of events, before anyone even listens to the stream. You should never do that in real code, instead only start adding events when the `onListen` is called, and stop again when `onPause` is called, until the subscription is resumed.

Here, the stream subscription gets stuffed up with a number of events, then it delivers one event, and then the subscription is paused.
The subscription dutifully reports that back to the controller.
Then the subscription gets a resume. This is where it gets clever. Since it already has events to deliver, it does *not* report the resume back to the controller. It doesn't actually want more events right now, there are plenty to deliver. And so it delivers the buffered events, one at a time, until the buffer is empty. At *that* point, it reports the resume back to the controller.

The controller reports that work has been resumed, but since nobody adds any more events, and nobody calls `close`, nothing further will happen.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great answer. I've read a lot of documentation, however, I did not find information about the subject. If you can give me a link to (or the name of a book), that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All right... I realise that the closing does not take effect immediately. So you can close the controller right after subscribing a listener to the stream : this will not "close everything abruptly". This controller is closed "when appropriate".

Comment: I'm not sure the exact behavior of a stream subscription is documented anywhere. It belongs be on the `StreamController`, so if it isn't, then it's only in the code.

Comment: *Closing* a controller doesn't do anything except scheduling a "done" event, and preventing you from adding more events to the controller. If there are other events buffered, those will be delivered before the "done" event. When the "done" event has been delivered, the `StreamController.done` future is completed.

Comment: ' it delievers the buffered events, at one second intervals, ' this is certainly not true for current versions of dart as it would severely limit events which from experience dart doesn't do.

Comment: ACK, yes, that was "one microtask" delays, not seconds. Will fix.